# Bagel Sponge: Room Temp or Proofing Temp?

Tags: bread, temperature, proofing, bagels

I have a new recipe to make deli-style bagels.  It calls to let the initial sponge stand in a large mixing bowl at room temperature for 2 hours, sealed with cellophane.

I have had troubles in the past with initial sponge/proofing.  I am fortunate now to have an oven with a proof setting that keeps the oven at a constant 90F.

I am worried that leaving it at room temperature won't be enough.  Would proofing at 90F be bad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of a sponge is to create more complex flavors by giving the yeast the opportunity for an additional low-and-slow fermentation step. If you speed the fermentation up by using a warmer environment, you won't get the intended flavors.

If your priority is on quick proofing, it would make more sense to use a recipe written for that, not to change the temperatures in a recipe optimized for other endpoints.